# Tight loop list copy creates a lot of garbage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, garbage-collection, xamarin, monogame

In a tight game loop, I do not want to generate any garbage for the GC to collect and cause the game to stutter. In many update loops, I have code that is very similar to this:

```
List<ModifierBase> activeModsCopy;
lock (lockObj)
{
    activeModsCopy = new List<ModifierBase>(_activeMods);
}
foreach (ModifierBase mod in activeModsCopy)
{
    mod.Update(elapsedGameTime);
}
```

The game runs at 60 FPS, thus the memory profiler reports a very large number of these temporary lists that I create to safe guard against the list being modified while being iterated through. What is a fast **garbage free** method to achieve the same result?

**Edit**: The code above runs in the update loop. There is no concurrency in the update loop, only 1 thread goes through it, but other threads can add or remove elements from the _activeMods list. Only 1 thread which does the updating has access to the activeModsCopy since its created in the update function.

Comment: Maybe you can limit the safe copies you need to make? If it's a tight game loop, how would somebody modify this list?

Comment: Do you want to leave your list available for chages while looping through it? Or would a `lock(_activeMods)` be enough for you?

Comment: @nvoigt there is 2 main ways the list could get modified, either after one of its elements is updated, then the element may wish to be removed or add more elements, or by other concurrent threads that may wish to modify the list. (But only 1 thread does the update call)

Comment: @AndréMeneses I am trying to avoid locks in a tight game loop.

Comment: maintain a list of added and deleted elements. After the loop add and delete elements according to these lists

Comment: If you have concurrency, then making a copy as you did is minimizing the potential errors, but it's not solving the problem.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys but the list of added and deleted elements themselves could get modified while iterating through them.

Comment: @Ramsay is it possible that two different iterations through the list are happening at the same time?

Comment: @nvoigt there is no concurrency in the update loop, only 1 thread goes through it, but other threads can add or remove elements from the _activeMods list. Only 1 thread which does the updating has access to the activeModsCopy.

Comment: But to create this copy, you have to read the list. If someone adds or deletes while the list is copied... that's a problem. If you have concurrency, you need locks. `new List<>()` is no magic concurrency solver.

Comment: @nvoigt You are right. Adding a lock would be correct, but this whole thing is creating a ton of garbage and a lot of pauses. I am searching for a better solution.

Comment: Keep 2 copies of the list. One for reading (that foreach) and other for manipulations. At the end of loop synchronize the list (by copying it entirely or by emptying and filling with elements from other one). If you create shallow list once in game loop cycle it won't create any significant amount of garbage.

Comment: @Ramsay Have you tried the following?

`using(List<ModifierBase> activeModsCopy = new List<ModifierBase>(_activeMods)){
foreach (ModifierBase mod in activeModsCopy)
{
    mod.Update(elapsedGameTime);
}}` Please let me know if this did any difference.

Comment: Does the order of elements in _ativeMods matter?

Comment: @AndréMeneses A `List<T>` does not implement `IDisposable`, and would make no impact on this problem even if it did.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa lets assume it does.

Answer (score 0):

What if you never delete the list and reuse it?

```
private ModifierBase[] _mods = new ModifierBase[2000]; 
private int _currentModsLength = 0;
```

you can use `List<ModifierBase>(2000)` if you wish for dyamically growing.

and your update:

```
public void Update()
{
   _currentModsLength = 0;
   // copy over!!
   lock(_activeMods){
      _currentModsLength = _activeMods.Length;
      for(var i = 0; i < _currentModsLength; i++){
         _mods[i] = _activeMods[i];
      }
   }

   for(var k = 0; k < _currentModsLength; k++)
      _mods[k].Update(..);
}
```

If you are still experiencing lag, it's most likely not the cause of list copying, but the fact that you are creating many mods and discarding them.

Alternatively, you might be able to switch your **List** and use **ConcurrentBag**. Basically, **ConcurrentBag** minimizes thread contention a little. So instead of List, **ConcurrentBag** has one list for each thread, and when you later want the combined list, it will lock each bag for microsecond.

There's unsafe option to bypass GC, using stack only:

```
ModifierBase* fib = stackalloc ModifierBase[_activeMods.Length];
// do copying over
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx

Comment: So would this be the correct list equivalent to your code that doesn't produce garbage? http://pastebin.com/jbAvRKUi

Comment: I need to use a list and not an array. Simply replacing your array with a list in your code doesn't work because it raises an 'out of range' exception  at _mods[i]=..., can only use the add method. And the list needs to be cleared to drop references after the update. I also found out that AddRange method of List creates garbage, so still don't know how to copy items efficiently

Comment: First: everything is possible with list that's possible with array, it's just more inconvenient, but has bigger flexibility in terms of performance. Second: List with Clear() SHOULD work, as it keeps the "array" internally, but only wipes out referenes, not the actual underlying array. You  need to be more explict by "creates garbage". What exactly do you mean by that? The only garbage, in my eyes, that you're producing right now is through _activeMods.Remove(). You should try and reuse those containers, instead of ditching the removed mod completely, add it to "USED MODS POOL"

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you and ModifierBase is ACTUALLY struct.

Comment: ModifierBase or any other I use are classes not struct. I could work on making a mod pool, but right now am focusing on the stuff that gets created every single frame. The problem with the code I have provided in the pastebin link is that I use AddRange() method to copy over the list during the update. But I found out that AddRange creates garbage everytime its called so I am not sure what to replace it with http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/574844-XNA-and-the-Garbage-Collector/

Comment: You still haven't defined what garbage means to you. Let me rephrase: 1) get out your memory profiler and SEE what is happening, post pictures. 2) List & AddRange DOES not produce any kind of garbage(except releasing _activeMod references), unless the underlying array needs RESIZE. If you use AddRange/Clear and the underlying array is big enough, there won't be any reallocations or movings, or anything for that matter. The only problem I see is that you are adding more elements to the list than you have specified in constructor(20). Make it 200, or 2000.

Comment: I did do a memory profiling and found that for collected allocations, AddRange (boils down to InsertRange) had 2K instances collected by the GC during a period of just 2 seconds. This is echoed by the previous web link I provided. I need a list instead of an array since I cannot know for sure how large I want the array to be. BTW I am developing a WP8 MonoGame app and I tested on device.

Comment: My definition of garbage is no longer needed heap objects that increase the chances of a garbage collection event to take place, which would pause my threads and cause the game to stutter. In my particular scenario I am using less that 20 mod objects so resizing is not an issue.

Comment: I can't help you much more, as I've already said: "List & AddRange DOES not produce any kind of garbage(except releasing _activeMod references), unless the underlying array needs RESIZE" and "the only problem I see is that you are adding more elements to the list than you have specified in constructor(20). Make it 200, or 2000."

If you still have problems, create a simple test project that demonstrates the problem. Ps, I've added "stackalloc keyword" which bypasses GC completely(by using stack), and I've had good results with it in the past, maybe it helps you.

Comment: I replaced AddRange with a foreach of the original list followed by a simple add for copying each element individually. Now when I do memory profiling I longer see garbage collection of lists in my update loop. So I guess this might be the solution.